# Extract the nodes 51 to 100 using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I do have an input XML as below. I would like to remove the empty tags, sort the parent nodes based on a specific child key and also extract only the parent nodes from 51 to 100 along with all their children C1 through CN.

I am getting the XML parser error in the below XSLT:

Input XML:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
              <class>
              <dept>
        <name>chemistry></name>
        <code>C001</code>
        <section>C1</section>
        <bldg>B</bldg>
     </dept>    
       <student rollno="393">
         <firstname>Dinkar</firstname>
         <lastname>Kad</lastname>
         <nickname>Dinkar</nickname>
         <marks>85</marks>
       </student>
       <student rollno="493">
         <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
         <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
         <nickname>Vinni</nickname>
         <marks>95</marks>
       </student>
       <student rollno="593">
         <firstname>Jasvir</firstname>
         <lastname>Singh</lastname>
         <nickname>Jazz</nickname>
         <marks>90</marks>
       </student>
       <student rollno="105">
         <firstname>Jasvir1</firstname>
         <lastname>Singh1</lastname>
         <nickname>Jazz1</nickname>
         <marks>90</marks>
       </student>
       <student rollno="102">
         <firstname>Jasvir2</firstname>
         <lastname>Singh2</lastname>
         <nickname>Jazz2</nickname>
         <marks>95</marks>
       </student>
       <noOfStud>3</noOfStud>
     </class>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:if test=".!=''">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="node()[boolean(normalize-space())]
                                |@*">
            </xsl:apply-templates>

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="C1" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/P1[position() &gt;= 51 and position() &lt;= 100]" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The example is confusing: are the parent nodes numbered P1, P2 ... PN or are they all named P1? If the former, then your `select="/root/P1[position() &gt;= 51 and position() &lt;= 100]"` will never select anything. -- I am also not sure what exactly you sort by(the C1 element does not appear to have a numerical value), and whether "*nodes 51 to 100*" means before sorting or after.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- extract only the parent nodes from 51 to 100 -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() &gt;= 51 and position() &lt;= 100]">
            <!-- sort the parent nodes based on a specific child  -->
            <xsl:sort select="C1" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove the empty tags -->
<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

In your modified example, you should make the second template similar to:

```
<xsl:template match="/class">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="dept"/>
        <!-- extract only the student nodes from 51 to 100 -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="student[position() &gt;= 51 and position() &lt;= 100]">
            <!-- sort the student nodes based on ???  -->
            <xsl:sort select="some-node" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="noOfStud"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for ur prompt response. It works fine.  but it prints less 2 parent nodes.  we asked to print the parent nodes from 51 to 100, it prints only 48 parent nodes.  does it count root as well?  also there is one leaf node missing at the end,  leaf node is used to print the number of parent nodes.  how to resolve these ?

Comment: I can only guess here, since I don't see your input, that some of the parent nodes have been removed as being empty.

Comment: Mike.. I have added the input file in my question.  I would like to start the extraction of nodes from student level,  so the result should display dept, numOfStud, and extracted student nodes.

Comment: You should not change the example so drastically at this point, as it may cause confusion. See if the addition to my answer solves the problem

Comment: Thanks Mike.  It worked.  Sorry for the drastic change.  I am new to this forum.  Ur advice noted.